# c# get pending windows updates. Updates that can't be found?

Tags: c#, windows, updates, windows-update

I pull all pending updates with this c# code:

```cs
using WUApiLib;

var updateSession = new UpdateSession();
var updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
updateSearcher.Online = false;

var searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 And IsHidden=0");
if (searchResult.Updates.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (IUpdate windowsUpdate in searchResult.Updates)
    {
        PendingUpdate update = new PendingUpdate();
        update.Title = windowsUpdate.Title;
        update.Description = windowsUpdate.Description;
        update.Downloaded = windowsUpdate.IsDownloaded;
        update.Urls = new List<string>();
        foreach (string url in windowsUpdate.MoreInfoUrls)
        {
            update.Urls.Add(url);
        }
        foreach (dynamic category in windowsUpdate.Categories)
        {
            update.Categories += category.Name + ", ";
        }
        pendingUpdates.Add(update);
    }
}
```

With this I get the pending windows updates I want but I also get updates, that I can't be found with "Search for windows updates" or even in the optional windows updates tab.

I don't want to install the updates, I just dont wan't the updates saved in my code if they cant be installed with the regular update functions of windows.

The two updates are "SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 3 (KB4022619)" and "Microsoft Silverlight (KB4481252)".
Can I somehow don't search for updates that can't be find over the windows update center?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the code and not that both products are out of support? Have you actually tried running Windows Update on that machine? Is the WU service working?

Comment: Does that mean that `UpdateSearcher` can find those updates, but they cant be downloaded anymore via windows updates because they are out of support? I tried to search for updates but it says that windows is up to date.